# How to convert wav file into 8000hz using Nodejs

Tags: node.js, nodes, ibm-watson, speech-to-text

I have tried to convert speech wav file to text using nodejs but it displays error like this:

> Error:
>
> data: '{\n "error": "This 8000hz audio input requires a narrow band
>   model."\n}',

Code :

```
let directory = `File Directory`;
let dirbuf = Buffer.from(directory);
let files = fs.readdirSync(directory);

// Create the stream.


// Pipe in the audio.
files.forEach(wav_files => {
//how can i convert that wav file into 8000hz and use that same wav file for speech to text convert
  fs.createReadStream(wav_files).pipe(recognizeStream);
  recognizeStream.on('data', function(event) { onEvent('Data:',event,wav_files); });
}
```

Comment: So, you need to resample your WAV file?

Comment: Yes, I need to convert my audio.wav file to 8000hz

Comment: Is there any reason why you wouldn't just use FFmpeg for this?  `ffmpeg -i input.wav -ar 8000 output.wav`

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure whether you've already explored [wav](https://github.com/rochars/wavefile) package or not. But I created a cheat like this:

```
const fs = require('fs');
const WaveFile = require('wavefile').WaveFile;

let wav = new WaveFile(fs.readFileSync("source.wav"));

// do it like this
wav.toSampleRate(8000);

// or like following way with your choice method
// wav.toSampleRate(44100, {method: "cubic"});

// write new file
fs.writeFileSync("target-file.wav", wav.toBuffer());
```

For complete running example clone [node-cheat wav-8000hz](https://github.com/zishon89us/node-cheat/blob/master/stackoverflow_answers/wav-8000hz/wav.js#L14) and run `node wav.js` followed by `npm i wavefile`.